# C# Winform Close a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a custom close image label, added it to a larger label, and added that to my panel. I have a bunch of these panels all over. I created a function to make this label collection which I then adds it to the panel. How do I create an event that closes the panel (Parent of Parent?) when a small close-style label is clicked? Here's what I have so far.

```
public void MakePanel1(string panel_name)
{
    Panel MyPanel = new Panel();
    Label TitleLabel = AddTitleLabel(panel_name);
    MyPanel.Controls.Add(TitleLabel);
    this.Controls.Add(MyPanel);
}

public Label AddTitleLabel(string title)
{
    Label TitleLabel = new Label();
    TitleLabel.Size = new Size(231, 20);
    TitleLabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    TitleLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    TitleLabel.Text = title;

    Label CloseLabel = new Label();
    CloseLabel.Size = new Size(16, 16);
    CloseLabel.Location = new Point(212, 2);
    CloseLabel.Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\..\pics\x.png");
    CloseLabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DoStuffAndClosePanel);
    TitleLabel.Controls.Add(CloseLabel);

    return TitleLabel;
}

private void DoStuffAndClosePanel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some stuff

    // Close the panel -- sender.Close() ?????
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "close" a panel? Collapse it? Remove it from the form? Make it invisible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do what you described you should know the panel control doesn't have a close method and you can:

```
private void DoStuffAndClosePanel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Do Stuff
    //...
    //Close Panel
    var parent=((Control)sender).Parent;
    parent.Visible = false;
    parent.Dispose();
    parent = null;
}
```

As another option you can use a Form instead of such panel. You can hide title bar of form and use your close button instead.

For example if you want to have such form:

```
public class PanelForm:Form
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

        switch (message.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MOVE)
                    return;
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
}
```

And the for showing such panel:

```
var f= new PanelForm();
f.TopLevel=false;
f.FormBorderStyle= System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
f.MinimizeBox=false;
f.MaximizeBox=false;
this.Controls.Add(f);
f.Show();
```

Or add it to a `TableLayoutPanel`, or `FlowLayoutPanel`

[image]

Another option could be using a `TabControl` and remove unwanted tabs.

Comment: Thank You. Now that I've thought about it some more, I don't actually need to close the panels, just make them invisible and move them around.